# Call setTimeout loop performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I was looking for a solution to call a function on `location.search` changed I didn't find anything something clean, so I choose to use the following code:

```
check_result_change()
function check_result_change() { 
    setTimeout(() => { 
        if (serach changed) { // do something } 
        check_result_change() 
    }, 3000) 
}
```

I am wondering if this solution can affect performance?

Comment: this is probably ok except for not calling clearTimeout (memory leak). Also calls to check_result_change should be throttled

Comment: @user3791775 Thanks, I found another function that does the same thing setInterval do you think that it can solve the problem of throttling and memory leak?
Because I need my function to keep called each 3 sec, I think clearTimeout won't help.

Comment: Yes, you should use setInterval, which will call the function periodically so you don't have to worry about the recursive call.